# WP_Query inside the loop creating unending loop

Tags: wordpress

On my Wordpress page I want to achieve the following:

---

**{TITLE OF PAGE}**

[image]

**{MY PAGE CONTENT}**

---

I've created a single post format image for the credit card icons and ran a wp-query to the contents of that single post. But once this query appears inside the loop, it loops through forever more ... *and* it never publishes my page content ... the output looks like the example below. How do I tell WP that I only want that row of icons to appear once and then go back to my page and publish the content?

---

**{My page title}**

[image]

**{Icons post title}**

[image]

**{Icons post title}**

[image]

**{Icons post title}**

[image]

etc etc etc

---

My wp_query however comes inside the loop and this is causing the images to appear first and then an infinite loop of the title of the post followed by the images.

My code is:

```
<?php
// Start the loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<!-- The following is included using get_template_part 
     But am copying the code here for ease of reading -->

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header class="entry-header"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <!-- Start WP Query for credit card images -->
        <?php
            $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
            $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query("category_name=credit-cards-accepted");
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="credit-cards"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- End WP Query for credit card images -->

        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    </article><!-- #post-## -->

<!-- Get template part ends -->
<!-- The remainder of the page.php template continues from here -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend naming the new query you are starting differently, so it doesn't interfere with the main loop. Try naming it $loop2 or something like that.

Also, be aware that with the way you are calling the loop, you are adding it to every post/article that is displayed from the regular page loop (in case you are displaying multiple posts there).

If you want to have it displayed like that:

- credit card image
- page post1
- page post2
- page post3 ...

You will need to call on it before the main loop (otherwise would call one article/post after the other and enter your image line there)
Try it like that:

```
<?php
    $loop2 = new WP_Query( array ('category_name'=> 'credit-cards-accepted' )); 

        while ($loop2->have_posts()) : $loop2->the_post(); 

        ?>
         <div class="credit-cards">             
          <?php the_content(); ?>
         </div>
        <?php
        endwhile; // end of the credit cards accepted loop. 
        ?>

 // Start the page loop.
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 ?>
```

Comment: Renaming the variable as $loop2 and adding wp_reset_postdata(); and wp_reset_postdata(); did work ... and it worked *inside* the loop. Brilliant! Appreciate it very much.

Comment: @TerryAlly Great, happy to hear I could help! Where did you add the wp_reset_postdata() ? I could update the answer with it (for me it works usually without wp_reset_postdata(), but I'm using new loops usually after putting out main loop content)

Answer (score 0):

You have to restore original post data after custom query and inner loop:

```
/* restore original post data after endwhile; */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

More about [wp_reset_postdata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)

EDIT:

You are probably also overriding $wp_query global somewhere because you are setting it to `$temp`. Also call `wp_reset_query()` to restore `$wp_query` and global post data to the original main query.

More about [wp_reset_query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query)